# "Recent reputation changes" for own profile, but "positive reputation changes" for foreign profile

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

If you open someone's profile page other than yourself, for example, [Chris Osiak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5481723/chris-osiak?tab=topactivity):

> [image: the empty reputation change summary on someone's profile other than you]

If open your own profile page:

> [image: the empty reputation change summary on your profile]

Why does it mention **positive changes** for others' profile?

Answer (score 2):

Because if their recent reputation changes are *only negative rep changes*, then the *summary* won't be shown at all. You can still see all public negative rep changes on their "reputation" tab though.

---

**Before downvote**

> [image: before downvote]

**After downvote** (after waiting until the caching breaks): reputation is decreased by 2, no change on the summary.

> [image: after downvote]

**On "Reputation" tab**: the downvote is still shown correctly

> [image: downvote on "reputation" tab]

---

**Before upvote**

> [image: before upvote]

**After upvote** (after waiting until the caching breaks): reputation is increased by 5, the summary is shown with recent reputation changes.

> [image: after upvote]